# Unable to resolve host, no address associated with hostname

Tags: android, android-volley

I just got started with Android Studio and made a small application. My problem is that i cannot connect to a website. I've added volley to my project to handle the responses. I searched other similar questions but all the responses suggested to add a permission to the manifest file(which i already have it).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When the request is being made i get back an error: `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "url goes here": No address associated with hostname`

The url works, i tried accessing it from my browser.
What can i do?

**EDIT**

```
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    Log.e("resp", response);
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Log.d("error", error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    VolleyCore.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: Could you post your code? We don't know where is thrown the error

Comment: It's just a simple string request. Currently I'm just outputting the result into my console (if it would actually work). The request is added to the queue if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: Post the code that you use to connect, not the manifest

Comment: I`ve edited my question

Comment: Have you or anyone recently (past two days) made changes to the domain name record of the domain in your url?

Comment: nope, it`s a openshift url